# Assigning a private variable to the value of a same-named variable from its parent scope

Tags: javascript, scope, variable-assignment

Can a private variable within a child scope be set to the value of a same-named private variable from its parent scope?

Consider the following:

```
var foo = 10;

function bar () {
  var f = foo, foo = f;
  return foo;
}

bar() // Returns 10
```

Can this be done without using the placeholder variable f?

```
var foo = 10;

function bar () {
  var foo = foo;
  return foo;
}

bar() // Want 10 but returns undefined.
```

I would like a solution that does not pass any arguments to bar. I realize that this isn't important for any reason other than aesthetics.

Comment: I'm curious why you want a solution to this at all--is there something specific you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, global variable is not visible since there is a local variable having the same name. In other words, local variable hides the global variable.

```
var foo = foo;
```

The declaration of `foo` ends only after reaching `;`. But trying to initializing `foo` to `foo` itself is undefined since it hasn't reached it's ending point of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll have to explicitly reference `foo` off of the parent scope.  Usually that will just be `this`, but you'll have to be careful in situations where your function may have been invoked via `apply` or `call`.  This, for example, should work:

```
var foo = 10;

function bar () {
  var foo = this.foo;
  return foo;
}

bar(); // 10
```

---

Edit: I need to make a correction, per @Felix' comment.  `this` will indeed usually refer to the global scope, rather than the parent scope.  Consider this for example:

```
var x = 'global';
(function () {
    var x = 'inner';
    (function() {
        var x = this.x;
        console.log(x); // 'global'
    })();
})();
```

Comment: It might work in this case, but in general, when calling a function this way, `this` refers to the global object, and not the "parent scope".

Comment: Or within an event handler where `this` gets bound, no?

Comment: @Felix - good point. Updated with a correction on that point.  Either way, this is probably a foolish way to do this - I was merely trying to demonstrate that, in some contexts, you can get this behavior w/out the temporary variable.